# How do you save the cursor attributes without saving position with escape sequence?

Tags: linux, console

printf '\e[s' will save the attributes and position of the cursor, so that the script can reset them using printf '\e[u'.  But I only want to save the attributes.  In other words, I want to change the color of text, print some text, and then restore the color settings at the end of the script.  If I use the [s and [u sequences, I will be resetting the position, which I do not want.

What's the easiest way to restore the color attributes to the cursor without restoring the position?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   ESC 7 (DECSC)   save state
   ESC 8 (DECRC)   restore most recently saved state
```

Didn't try it out though ...

Comment: This also restores the position of the cursor. Is there a way to restore only the attributes and not cursor position?